# Validate email address with folder using regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am writing a regular expression to validate an email address in JavaScript.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]([\w-\.]{4,29})+@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/
```

This is working fine. But there came an additional requirement like " In a GMAIL address we can specify the folder name along with the email id to which the mail will be delivered. For ex. james+office@gmail.com , the mail will be delivered to the folder "office" under james@gmail.com's inbox.

So how can I validate that also in the above regex. The Plus symbol is not mandatory but if + is added it should be **in between the other characters before @ symbol**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add the `+` character inside of your character class and use a negated match before the `@`. **Note** that I removed the escape sequence from the dot and moved the hyphen as the last character, or else you need to escape it and also implemented the use of the `i` modifier for case-insensitive matching.

```
/^[a-z]([\w.+-]{4,29})[^+]@([\w-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3}$/i
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nS3gX8)

Comment: I agree with about adding it to `[\w.+-]`, for the reason that your initial regex doesn't seem to really care where some chars appear, for instance you are allowing a dot just before the `@`... So why now also allow the `+` there. +1

Comment: @hwnd You mistook what I said. Yes, it should be before @ but "in between the username" like james+office@gmail.com, not like james+@gmail.com which is invalid. So this breaks in the above regex you provided.

Comment: @VishnuY I updated my answer, is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

use this one instead:

```
/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i
```

Comment: what is this exactly isn't it too long?

Comment: this is a standard regular expression to validate your email address, it is pretty robust

Comment: i tried to run it in regex101.com and its not working over there

Answer (score 0):

I tried this RegEx in the desired scenario you required and it worked fine

`^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\+]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$`

Try it in [RegEx Validator](http://regex101.com/r/oH3oA3)

Thanks,
Hope it helps